# Ubuntu 23.10 "Full Screen" Game displays blank horizontal bar and effect of ALT+TAB

Tags: games, steam, wayland, fullscreen, 23.10

This seems to be a regression under Ubuntu 23.10 at first glance.

**Environment**

On a vanilla Ubuntu 23.10 setup, when I start Civilization V under Steam, overlay is off, in full screen mode when the the game launcher starts:

90% of the time I get a horizontal blank(white) band that is about the height of a menu bar.[![Civ V with blank bar][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARmwb.jpg

When this happens the mouse pointer and any buttons or clickable items are not aligned. In the photo above the mouse must be placed below the 'Click to Continue' in order to trigger the continue event.

Occasionally , 5%  of the time ?, I get multiple blank bands at the top and once there was a vertical blank band on the left also along with the horizontal blank band.

Occasionally, The remaining 5% of the time the game launcher is displayed correctly.

Under Ubuntu 22.10 & 22.04 on the same hardware I never observed these problems. I tried a few other games but they did not exhibit this problem.

**Work Around**
If I press ALT+TAB multiple times eventually the blank band(s) will go away. Once fixed pressing ALT+TAB will again display the blank horizontal band.

**Question**

Is this issue only showing up now because of the move to wayland ? Is it more likely there is a latent bug in the game or an issue with wayland comparability libraries ?

Comment: Civilization V is a Native Linux game so does not use proton

Answer (score -1):

It could very well be related to the shift to Wayland - however, my first stop when investigating game performance on Linux is [ProtonDB](https://www.protondb.com/).

In the case of [Civilization V](https://www.protondb.com/app/8930), some other folks have reported the same issues that you have seen, under different system configurations (some using Steam Flatpak, some running under Fedora / Arch / etc.). Several potential fixes are mentioned there, such as trying the Linux native build if Proton is giving trouble (or vice versa), or continuing to use the workaround, but this doesn't appear to be a uniquely Ubuntu-related issue.